# Joomla SQL query alternative

Tags: mysql, joomla

I have the following getListQuery() in my model. I want to add another join (see further) and was wondering if the level part could be done another way (without GROUP_CONCAT):

```
protected function getListQuery()
{   

    $db    = $this->getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select(
        $this->getState(
            'list.select',
            'a.id AS id,' .
            'a.dbid AS dbid,' .
            'a.alias AS alias,' .
            'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT l.level ORDER BY l.level ASC) as `levels`'
        )
    );

    $query->from('#__maintable AS a');

    $query->join('LEFT', '#__leveltable AS l ON l.dbid = a.dbid');

    $query->group($db->quoteName('a.id'));

    $query->order($db->escape($this->state->get('list.ordering', 'a.id') . ' ' . $db->escape($this->state->get('list.direction', 'ASC'))));

    return $query;

}
```

In the leveltable there can be more then one row with a corresponding 'dbid'.
I would also like to add a second table which has a relation to 'dbid' which also can have multiple rows with the same 'dbid' and it has more fields I would require then just the 'level' field from leveltable.

Comment: `SELECT` column list and `GROUP BY` does not match. You could get any result for columns that are not aggregated plus from MySQL 5.7 this kind of operation could return error.